# Unicode characters in CLGeocoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, unicode

I have a search bar where you can search for cities/countries/places. I tested it out and searched for Tokyo. My results are presented in a search display controller's table view. Here is an example of what I get when I search up 'Tokyo', presented in a table view cell:

[image: This is a <code>UITableViewCell</code>]

And I have a string that combines the cell's title and subtitle. I then reverse geocode that string, however I get an error because it cannot recognize that 'Tokyo' because the letter ''' is a unicode character.

So is there a way to convert this string/'o' to make it a regular 'o' or have no unicode characters? Or is there a way to let `CLGeocoder` be able to geocode these types of characters

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you need to remove all diacritics in the string.

See Documentations for `CFMutableString` Reference :

```
Boolean CFStringTransform (
   CFMutableStringRef string,
   CFRange *range,
   CFStringRef transform,
   Boolean reverse
);
```

set the `transform` parameter to `kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics`:

```
NSMutableString *StripDiacritics(NSString *string)
{
    CFMutableStringRef stringRef = (__bridge_retained CFMutableStringRef)[string mutableCopy];
    CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(stringRef));
    CFStringTransform(stringRef, &range, kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics, false);
    NSMutableString *result = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableString*)stringRef;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do this with an NSString, I am not so sure how to make this work